# PHP clearing variables between require file?

Tags: php

I have a require for a file in my php code.  This require exists twice in the code.

```
require 'test.php';

echo $result;

require 'test.php';
```

Is there a way to clear all the variables the first require sets before running the second require on the exact same file?

Comment: Why don't you make test.php a class?

Comment: Making a class is too complex for me...I just have one single php page...

Comment: Do you mean you want to clear the scope after the first `require 'test.php'` has been included?

Comment: I mean, use OOP, your problem is asking for it.

Comment: ouh, this is very bad practice... but as it seems you use global variables sooo: get an array of variables via array_diff(get_defined_vars(), $GLOBALS) and unset() them

Comment: @Erik still, an object has to bound to a variable at some point, what's your point?

Comment: @dbf - If scope means resetting all the variables between the files then yes that is what I am trying to do...

Comment: @dbf my point is that he can initialize two instances of test.php if it was an object and thus separate the logic and the variables to the two instances.

Comment: See @Najzero, also his first sentence, that this is something you should avoid, although respected programs like phpMyAdmin use this technique, you should really avoid it and change your approach

Comment: @Erik, do we know the contents of test.php and state that the requirements for OOP are appropriate?

Comment: As the OP does not know how to do functions (see comment below @Mathieu Imberts answer), any sensible answer will be too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the `require` in a function, if you don't use global vars. In that case all the  variables you create will be limited to the function scope.

```
function includeFile() {
    require 'test.php';
    echo $result;
}

includeFile();

includeFile();
```

But it would be much better to create a class as it was suggested in the comments.

Comment: Would this still work if I used a loop to run the require twice instead of a function? (I don't know how to do functions...)

Comment: @David19801 Yes in that case you could run a loop.

Comment: The other answers look good and maybe better but this is what I used because I understand it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IF you declare all your variables at the beginning of your require like:

```
$var = false;
$var2 = 0;
$var3 = '';
// etc...
```

You wouldn't have to do anything other than require the file again - the variables would automatically be reset to an initial state by these declarations.

That being said, what you are looking to do cries out for a different approach.  Either encapsulate that functionality into a function or a class depending on how you need to use it.  Basically, if you have some code you are repeating throughout your codebase, you should modularize it, and definitely not pollute the global scope with variables only needed for that intermal functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do.  `unset()` will delete all those variables.  That answers your question.

What you should do is look into OOP and classes.  Make a class, then make an instance of that class.  You can then make a new class and have completely different values and data, ultimately disabling the need to `unset()` and `require` again.

Answer (score 0):

**I did not test this code!**

Point is get the list of defined vars before inclusion, include file, get the list of defined vars after inclusion, compute difference, unset global variables based on that difference, include file.

See manual entries on [`get_defined_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) and [`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

```
<?php

$old_vars = get_defined_vars();

require 'test.php';

$new_vars = get_defined_vars();

echo $result;

$diff_vars = array_diff_key($old_vars, $new_vars);
while ($var = key($diff_vars)) {
    unset($GLOBALS[$var]);
    next($diff_vars);
}
unset($old_vars, $new_vars, $diff_vars);

require 'test.php';
```

Makes sense?